Configuring OpenLdap for high concurrency
We have used docker image of openldap from below link:
https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/tree/635034a75878773f8576d646422cf26e43741fab?tab=readme-ov-file#beginner-guide
The ldap is being run on single pod as of now.
Can anyone suggest which parameters  should be configured for high concurrency?
Additional info can be provided if needed.
Thanks in advance !!
Parameters for supporting high concurrency in OpenLdap

OpenLDAP is already built for that. Off topic.
